# C# randomly pick elements from one array to move to another

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I'm still learning C# so bear with me as I attempt to explain. Basiclly what I'm trying to do is deal a deck of cards. So arrayA (arrayGameBlessings in my example) has 52 elements and I want to move 10 cards to arrayB (arrayBlessings) while also removing them from arrayA. Here's what I got so far

```
for (int i = 0; i <= arrayGameBlessings.Length; i++)
{
    int bless = rnd.Next(arrayBlessings.Length);
    arrayGameBlessings[i] = arrayBlessings[bless];
    arrayBlessings = arrayBlessings.Where(w => w != arrayBlessings[bless]).ToArray();
}
```

But this doesn't do anything as far as I can tell...  What would be the best way to achieve something like this? Preferably a super simple one, two line method that's easy to understand and modify. Thanks!

Comment: `List` would be better suited to this than an `Array`

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: More specifically `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` would be the right choice

Comment: SO is a site to get specific programming questions answered, not to have your code written for you. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Hint: use an object of the Random class to generate a number between 0 and 51. Random rnd = new Random(); int index = rnd.Next(0, 51); Do that 10 times. Well you also need to keep track of what cards were already picked, but you get the point :)

Comment: Hi sorry, new to this site, but I updated it with what I've tried so far, but it doesn't work as far as I can tell so... how exactly would I use a list? I literally just started C# like 2 days ago

Comment: A list is not needed for shuffling. An array is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not wrong per se, the only detail is that the `for` should use `<` instead of `<=`, that is:

```
void Main()
{
    var arrayBlessings = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    var arrayGameBlessings = new int[5];
    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayGameBlessings.Length; i++)
    {
        int bless = rnd.Next(arrayBlessings.Length);
        arrayGameBlessings[i] = arrayBlessings[bless];
        arrayBlessings = arrayBlessings.Where(w => w != arrayBlessings[bless]).ToArray();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(arrayBlessings);
    Console.WriteLine(arrayGameBlessings);
}
```

Note: code tested on [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

---

With that said, your approach is very inneficient. Each call to `ToArray` will create a new array, which is too much. Instead you may want to try `List<T>`:

```
void Main()
{
    const int amount_to_deal = 5;
    var arrayBlessings = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    var arrayGameBlessings = new List<int>();
    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount_to_deal; i++)
    {
        int bless = rnd.Next(arrayBlessings.Count);
        arrayGameBlessings.Add(arrayBlessings[bless]);
        arrayBlessings.RemoveAt(bless);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(arrayBlessings);
    Console.WriteLine(arrayGameBlessings);
}
```

---

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172840/c-sharp-randomly-pick-elements-from-one-array-to-move-to-another#comment30073118_20172840) by [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan), an array would be enough to shuffle, for example the following code will shuffle the array:

```
void Main()
{
    var array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        int j = i + rnd.Next(array.Length - i);
        var tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Card dealing is typically done like this:

1. Perform a shuffle.
2. Pick the first N cards from the shuffled array.

A shuffle is done like so. Put integers 0 to 51 into an array. Then shuffle them with, for instance, Fisher-Yates shuffle. Perhaps like this:

```
int[] shuffle()
{
    int[] cards = Enumerable.Range(0, 52).ToArray();
    for (int i = cards.Length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        int j = random.Next(i);
        int temp = cards[j];
        cards[j] = cards[i-1];
        cards[i-1] = temp;
    }
    return cards;
}

int[] deal(int N)
{
    int[] result = new int[N];
    Array.Copy(shuffle(), 0, result, N);
    return result;
}
```

If you wanted to be more adventurous you could adapt the shuffle to pick just N cards.

You don't need to remove any elements from the shuffled deck. You just need to remember how many you took so far. And even then, you only need to do that if you are going to take any more at a later time without a new shuffle.

Comment: So after the shuffle how exactly would you take said N cards from one array to the other? The randomizing isn't nessicarly the problem, it's the transferring from one array to the other. Again if this is a stupid basic question, sorry like I said I'm brand new to C#

Comment: Just copy the first N elements into a new array. And the shuffle will be an issue. It's very easy to do it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
//I assume you have a Card class, but this can be anything, integers, for example 
void MoveRandomCards(List<Card> source, List<Card> dest, int cards)
{
  var rnd = new Random();
  for(int i = 0;i<cards && source.Count>0;i++)
  {
    // random card position to remove from source
    var idxSrc = rnd.Next(source.Count);
    // random position in destination to insert new card
    var idxDst = rnd.Next(dest.Count);
    dest.Add(idxDst, source[idxSrc]);
    source.RemoveAt(idxSrc);
  }
}
```